# duplicate entry for key primary errors while replicating a table

Tags: mysql, sql, pandas

I have some CRM data that exists in a MS SQL server, that I must move to mysql daily.  I've got some python-pandas, read_sql() and to_sql() scripts that move the tables.  I'm running into duplicate primary keys errors after doing some upsert logic. I have the GUID from CRM as the primary key for the table - in MySQL it is a varchar(64) datatype.  Unsure what's triggering the duplicate warning.

mysql_table:

```
GUID-PK          Name      favorite_number  modifiedon
00000B9D...      Ben            10          '2017-01-01'
000A82A5...      Harry          9           '2017-05-15'
000A9896...      Fred           5           '2017-12-19'
```

(the GUIDs are longer, i'm shortening for the example)
I pull all the new records from MS SQL into a temporary table in MySQL based on modified dates that are greater than my current table.  Some of these could be new records some could be records that already exist in my current table but have been updated.

mysql_temp_table:

```
GUID-PK          Name      favorite_number  modifiedon
00000B9D...      Ben            15          '2018-01-01'
000A82BB...      John           3           '2018-03-15'
000A4455...      Ray            13          '2018-04-01'
```

I want to replace any modified records, straight up, so I delete all the common records from the mysql_table. In this example, I want to remove Ben from the mysql_table, so that it can be replaced by Ben from the mysql_temp_table:

```
DELETE FROM mysql_table WHERE GUID-PK IN (SELECT GUID-PK FROM mysql_temp_table)
```

Then I want to just move the whole temp table into the replicated table with:

```
INSERT INTO mysql_table (SELECT * FROM temp_table)
```

But that gives me an error:

```
"Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'") [SQL: 'INSERT INTO mysql_table SELECT * FROM mysql_temp_table'
```

I can see that many of the GUID's start with '000', it seems like this is being interpreted as '0'.  Shouldn't this be caught in the Delete-IN statement from above.  i'm stuck on where to go next. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check whether the delete worked? Can you post the definition of the two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the DELETE statement operation is failing with an error.

That's because the dash character isn't a valid character in an identifier. If the column name is really `GUID-PK`, then that needs to be properly escaped in the SQL text, either by enclosing it in backticks (the normal pattern in MySQL), or if `sql_mode` includes `ANSI_QUOTES`, then the identifiers can be enclosed in double quotes.

---

Another possibility is that `temp_table` does not have a PRIMARY or UNIQUE KEY constraint defined on the `GUID-PK` column, and there are multiple rows in `temp_table` that have the same value for `GUID-PK`, leading to a duplicate key exception on the INSERT into mysql_table.

Another guess (since we're not seeing the definition of the temp_table) is that the columns are in a different order, such that `SELECT * FROM temp_table` isn't returning columns in the order expected in `mysql_table`.  I'd address that issue by explicitly listing the columns, of both the target table for the INSERT, and in the SELECT list.

---

Given that that GUID-PK column is a unique key, I would tend to avoid two separate statements (a DELETE followed by an INSERT), and just use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement.

```
INSERT INTO mysql_table (`guid-pk`, `name`, `favorite_number`, `modifiedon` )
SELECT s.`guid-pk`, s.`name`, s.`favorite_number`, s.`modifiedon`
  FROM temp_table s
 ORDER
    BY s.`guid-pk`
 ON DUPLICATE KEY
 UPDATE `name`            = VALUES( `name` )
      , `favorite_number` = VALUES( `favorite_number` )
      , `modifiedon`      = VALUES( `modifiedon` )
```

Comment: Both these answers were helpful - thank you.  I just wanted to note, because I don't have rep to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You may have AUTOCOMMIT disabled.

If you are performing both actions in the same TRANSACTION and do not have AUTOCOMMIT enabled your second READ COMMITTED statement will fail.  INSERTS, UPDATES, and DELETES are executed using the READ COMMITTED Isolation Level

Your INSERT is being performed on the data set as it appeared before your DELETE.  You need to either:

A.  Explicitly COMMIT your DELETE within the TRANSACTION

or

B.  Split the two statements into individual TRANSACTIONs

or

C.  Renable AUTOCOMMIT

If this is not the case you will need to investigate your data sets for your DELETE and INSERT statements, because a DELETE will not just fail silently.

Comment: Both these answers were helpful - thank you.  I just wanted to note, because I don't have rep to upvote.